# How to spool file1 or file2 from a single SQL file based on the input?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a SQL file like the following:

```
SET ECHO OFF
set feed off
set verify off
set head off
set pagesize 0
set space 0
set trimspool on
set line 250
spool subir.rpt

select 'Subir' from dual;
spool off

SET ECHO OFF
set feed off
set verify off
set head off
set pagesize 0
set space 0
set trimspool on
set line 250
spool vishal.rpt

select 'vishal' from dual;
spool off
```

Let's call this file spool.sql. I need to enable creation of spool file based on the input spool.sql file receives. For example, if it receives "subir.rpt" The first portion of the SQL file should run and subir.rpt should be produced; if it is vishal.rpt, the second portion should run and vishal.rpt should get generated.

How can this be achieved?

Edit: This SQL file is getting called from a shell script. The shellscript is like the following:

```
sqlplus -s dbread$HOST_CONNECT_STR/dbread<<endplus
@spool.sql
endplus
```

Answer (score 0):

What is launching this spool.sql? A shell script? Database function?

If it's a shell script, I would either use a parameter to this script or split it into two separate .sql files and call the appropriate one.

You could also save the file value into a temporary table prior to calling this script and select it before spooling the file.

There are a lot of options but it all depends on how you call this script and how extensible you want it to be.

Comment: It is getting called from a shellscript. I have edited my question to include that. Also I want to accumulate both queries in the same SQL file because in the real problem, there are many such SQL queries and I can not make different files for each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use the supplied parameter dynamically as the spoolfile:

```
set echo off
set feed off
set verify off
set head off
set pagesize 0
set space 0
set trimspool on
set line 250

spool &1

spool

select 'Subir' from dual where '&1' = 'Subir.rpt';

select 'vishal' from dual where '&1' = 'vishal.rpt';

spool off
```

(The `spool` command on its own is just to print the current spoolfile name for demo purposes.)